# How can I find out what assertion failed, from an iOS crash log?

Tags: ios, debugging, uislider, crash-reports, assertions

I have a symbolicated crash log from Xcode with the following lines:

```
3   Foundation   0x185a20a1c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112 (NSException.m:152)
4   UIKit        0x18a31b044 -[UISlider _setValue:minValue:maxValue:andSendAction:] + 224 (UISlider.m:1396)
5   MyApp        0x10013cea8 -[RecordingPlayer updateRecordingControls:fullUpdate:] + 284 (RecordingPlayer.m:1448)
```

I can tell from the last line that the app is crashing when I set the `maximumValue` property of a `UISlider`. And I can guess from the other two lines that my app is trying to set that property to an invalid value. But is there any way to find out exactly what assertion failed?

If I could find an explanation like "maximumValue must be greater than 0," that would help me understand where in my code this bad value is getting calculated.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem on my own devices, so I can't debug to inspect the values when the crash occurs.

Comment: I suspect the main assertion to be max value > min value. Create an assertion like this in your RecordingPlayer class?

Comment: I could do that, but to be sure that's the problem, I'd have to release another app version and wait to see if the crash happens again. I'd like to know that it's fixed in my next release if possible.

Comment: Actually, I just tried setting the minimumValue of a slider to 10 and the maximumValue to 5 and that didn't trigger an assertion failure. I also tried setting maximumValue to -1 and that didn't trigger a failure either. In any case, it would be best to know what assertion is failing, as a more general troubleshooting tool.